# How to build a data analysis pipeline procedure

Tags: pipeline

I have a series of scripts. Some are in R, some in Python, and others in SAS. I have built them in such a way that one code outputs a .csv file that the next code obtains and then that code outputs a .csv file, and so on...

I want to create a script that will automatically run each script in order so that the final output can be generated automatically.

What language would be best for this and can anyone point me to any examples of the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a windows OS: you can use a Power-Shell script and windows scheduler for scheduling.

If you are using Unix OS: you can use Shell script and Crontab for scheduling.